# Impact of the parameter dimension in gather function

Tags: torch

I am trying to use the [gather](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html?highlight=gather#torch.gather) function in pytorch but can't understand the role of `dim` parameter.

Code:

```
t = torch.Tensor([[1,2],[3,4]])
print(torch.gather(t, 0, torch.LongTensor([[0,0],[1,0]])))
```

Output:

```
 1  2
 3  2
[torch.FloatTensor of size 2x2]
```

Dimension set to 1:

```
print(torch.gather(t, 1, torch.LongTensor([[0,0],[1,0]])))
```

Output becomes:

```
 1  1
 4  3
[torch.FloatTensor of size 2x2]
```

How, `gather` function actually works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized how the gather function works.

```
t = torch.Tensor([[1,2],[3,4]])
index = torch.LongTensor([[0,0],[1,0]])
torch.gather(t, 0, index)
```

Since the `dimension` is zero, so the output will be:

```
| t[index[0, 0], 0]   t[index[0, 1], 1] |
| t[index[1, 0], 0]   t[index[1, 1], 1] |
```

If the `dimension` is set to one, the output will become:

```
| t[0, index[0, 0]]   t[0, index[0, 1]] |
| t[1, index[1, 0]]   t[1, index[1, 1]] |
```

So the formula is:

```
For a 3-D tensor the output is specified by:

out[i][j][k] = input[index[i][j][k]][j][k]  # if dim == 0
out[i][j][k] = input[i][index[i][j][k]][k]  # if dim == 1
out[i][j][k] = input[i][j][index[i][j][k]]  # if dim == 2
```

Reference: http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html?highlight=gather#torch.gather

Answer (score 3):

Just add to the existing answer, one application of `gather` is to collect scores along a designated dimension.

For instance we have such settings:

- 3 classes and 5 examples
- Each class is assigned of a score, do it for every example
- Objective is to collect scores indicated by the labels `y`

The code is as the follows

```
torch.manual_seed(0)

num_examples = 5
num_classes = 3
scores = torch.randn(5, 3)

#print of scores
scores: tensor([[ 1.5410, -0.2934, -2.1788],
        [ 0.5684, -1.0845, -1.3986],
        [ 0.4033,  0.8380, -0.7193],
        [-0.4033, -0.5966,  0.1820],
        [-0.8567,  1.1006, -1.0712]])


y = torch.LongTensor([1, 2, 1, 0, 2])
res = scores.gather(1, y.view(-1, 1)).squeeze()
```

Outputs:

```
#print of gather results
tensor([-0.2934, -1.3986,  0.8380, -0.4033, -1.0712])
```