# Pytorch - how do I index a 2-D matrix row wise?

Tags: pytorch

I would like to index a 2-D matrix row-wise and re-assign values.

For example, first consider a 1-D vector case where we have three 1-D tensors `t1, indexes, t2` with the same shape. We can do this indexing and re-assignment as follows:

```py
indexes = torch.tensor([0, 2, 1, 3])
t1 = torch.tensor([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
t2 = torch.tensor([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])

t1[indexes] = t2
```

Now, say that `t1, indexes, t2` are 2-D matrices instead of 1-D vectors and have the same shape `(R X C)`. I would like to do similar indexing as above for every row in these matrices where:

```py
for i in range(R):
    t1[i][indexes[i]] = t2[i]
```

I would like to vectorize this operation instead of using a for loop. How do I do this?

Comment: [`torcg.gather()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the gather function do in pytorch in layman terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999977/what-does-the-gather-function-do-in-pytorch-in-layman-terms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similiar to @Anubhav's answer with a slight change in dimension of `scatter_`, this did the job. Source: [PyTorch Discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-do-i-index-a-2-d-matrix-row-wise/49915)

```py
indexes = torch.tensor([[0, 2, 1, 3],
                        [1, 0, 3, 2]])
t1 = torch.zeros_like(indexes).float()
t2 = torch.tensor([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
                   [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]])
t1.scatter_(1, indexes, t2)
```

Comment: I discussed the same technique in my solution above as well. So, in place of adding one more answer using the same technique, you could have commented that second solution worked. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question @Anubhav but the reason I posted another solution and did not accept yours was because of the difference in the dimensionality of `scatter_` to achieve the expected outcome. I've modified my answer to refer to yours as well :) Thanks again for answering!

Answer (score 3):

So, in order to do `multi-index` selection, you can use [torch.gather](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather) function, which gathers values along an axis specified by dim(second parameter).

**Example 1:**

```
t2 = torch.tensor([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], 
                   [0.8, 1.8, 0.2, 0.3], 
                   [0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4]])
indexes1 = torch.tensor([[0, 2, 0, 2], 
                         [0, 1, 1, 0], 
                         [0, 0, 1, 2]])
t1 = torch.gather(t2, 0, indexes1) # dim is 0
print(t1)
```

output:

```
tensor([[0.1000, 0.1000, 0.3000, 0.4000],
        [0.1000, 1.8000, 0.2000, 0.4000],
        [0.1000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.4000]])
```

**Example 2:**

```
t2 = torch.tensor([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], 
                   [0.8, 1.8, 0.2, 0.3], 
                   [0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4]])
indexes2 = torch.tensor([[0, 3, 2, 0], 
                         [0, 1, 1, 3], 
                         [0, 0, 3, 2]])  
t1 = torch.gather(t2, 1, indexes2) # dim is 1
print(t1)
```

output:

```
tensor([[0.1000, 0.4000, 0.3000, 0.1000],
        [0.8000, 1.8000, 1.8000, 0.3000],
        [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.4000, 0.2000]])
```

To know more about `torch.gather` function, just go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999977/what-does-the-gather-function-do-in-pytorch-in-layman-terms) SO discussion.

You can also use `torch.Tensor.scatter_` to do the same.

`t1.scatter_(0, indexes, t2)` basically says send the elements of `t2` tensor to the following indices(specified in `indexes` tensor) in `t1` tensor, row-wise(dim 0).

**Example:**

```
t1 = torch.zeros((3, 4))
t2 = torch.tensor([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], 
                   [0.8, 1.8, 0.2, 0.3], 
                   [0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4]])
indexes = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 0, 2], 
                        [0, 1, 2, 1], 
                        [2, 0, 1, 0]])
t1 = t1.scatter_(0, indexes, t2)
print(t1)
```

output:

```
tensor([[0.8000, 0.1000, 0.3000, 0.4000],
        [0.1000, 1.8000, 0.2000, 0.3000],
        [0.5000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.4000]])
```

You can read more about it from [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_).

Comment: what about assignment to the gathered entries? that was the point of the question.