# Slicing a 4D tensor with a 3D tensor-index in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, slice, tensor

I have a **4D tensor** (which happens to be a *stack of three batches* of 56x56 images where each batch has 16 images) with the size of **[16, 3, 56, 56]**. My goal is to select the correct one of those three batches (with my index map that has the size of **[16, 56, 56]**) for each pixel and get the images that I want.

Now, I want to **select** the particular batches of images inside those three batches, with a  which has values such as

```
       [[[ 0,  0,  2,  ...,  0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  2,  ...,  0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0,  ...,  0,  0,  0],
         ...,
         [ 0,  0,  0,  ...,  0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  2,  0,  ...,  0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  2,  2,  ...,  0,  0,  0]],

        [[ 0,  2,  0,  ...,  1,  1,  0],
         [ 0,  2,  0,  ...,  0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0,  ...,  0,  2,  0],
         ...,
         [ 0,  0,  0,  ...,  0,  2,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  2,  ...,  0,  2,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  2,  ...,  0,  0,  0]]]
```

So for the 0s, the value will be selected from the first batch, where 1 and 2 will mean I want to select the values from the second and the third batch.

Here are some of the visualizations of the indices, each color denoting another batch.

[image]

[image]

I have tried to transpose the 4D tensor to match the dimensions of my indices, but it did not work. All it does is to give me a copy of the dimensions I have tried to select. Means

```
tposed = torch.transpose(fourD, 0,1) print(indices.size(),
outs.size(), tposed[:, indices].size())
```

outputs

```
torch.Size([16, 56, 56]) torch.Size([16, 3, 56, 56]) torch.Size([3, 16, 56, 56, 56, 56])
```

while the shape I need is

```
torch.Size([16, 56, 56]) or torch.Size([16, 1, 56, 56])
```

and as an example, if I try to select the right values for only the first image on the batch with

```
fourD[0,indices].size()
```

I get a shape like

```
torch.Size([16, 56, 56, 56, 56])
```

Not to mention that I get an out of memory error when I try this on the whole tensor.

I appreciate any help for **using these indices to select either one of these three batches for each pixel in my images**.

Note :

I have tried the option

```
outs[indices[:,None,:,:]].size()
```

and that returns

```
torch.Size([16, 1, 56, 56, 3, 56, 56])
```

Edit : torch.take does not help much since it treats the input tensor as a single dimensional array.

Comment: I have started to suspect that what I need is the function torch.take, but I believe I'll have to investigate further

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999977/what-does-the-gather-function-do-in-pytorch-in-layman-terms it seems like gather function is just what I am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there is a function in PyTorch that has the functionality I was searching for.

```
torch.gather(fourD, 1, indices.unsqueeze(1))
```

did the job.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51032153/776348) is a beautiful explanation of what gather does.

Comment: Facing the same issue, could you please share an example of the `indices` you are using?

Comment: hi, kindly see the details in the question. Indices are 3d tensors made of {0,1,2}. The indices point to the channels that need to be yielded for each pixel in each instance in the batch.