# How does `torch.gather()` construct new tensors?

Tags: pytorch

I'm struggling to understand what the function [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) is doing.

If I have:

```
a = torch.tensor([[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
b = torch.tensor([[1,1],[1,2]])
```

Then

```
>>> torch.gather(input=a, dim=1, index=b)
tensor([[5, 5],
        [8, 9]])
```

While

```
>>> torch.gather(input=a, dim=0, index=b)
tensor([[ 7,  8],
        [ 7, 11]])
```

Can somebody explain **very simply** how these output tensors are actually constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first call you index `a` with `b` along `dim=1` (2nd dimension). The performed operation is:

```
out[i,j] = a[i, b[i,j]]
```

Which returns:

```
[[ a[0, b[0,0]], a[0, b[0,1]] ],
 [ a[1, b[1,0]], a[1, b[1,1]] ]]
```

While on the second call, you index `a` with `b` along `dim=0` (1st dimension). This time around:

```
out[i,j] = a[b[i,j], j]
```

Which returns:

```
[[ a[b[0,0], 0], a[b[0,1], 1] ],
 [ a[b[1,0], 0], a[b[1,1], 1] ]]
```

*For more explanations, read on with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999977/what-does-the-gather-function-do-in-pytorch-in-layman-terms).*